# Angular2 http.get chaining

Tags: angular, http, typescript, rxjs

I have the following chain of http.get in my service:

```
constructor(private http:Http) {}

getDetails(sysID:string){

var details;
this.http.get('https://blahURL').map(res => res.json().filter(f => f.id == another.id)[0]).subscribe(
    (data) => details = data,             // Reach here if res.status >= 200 && <= 299
    (err) => console.log(err),            // Reach here if fails
    function(){                           // On completion

      console.log(this);

      this.http.get(...) //<- fails
```

The "on Completion" function gets triggered, but the `this` I get in the console is a SafeSubscriber object, so the next http call for `this.http`fails.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Before the this.http call, assign _this_ to a new variable:

`let that = this;` and in the callback use `that.http.get(...)` see if that works, it looks like the _this_ context is lost

Comment: I don't understand you wrong parentheses, you have  .map(res => res.json().filter, it must be .map(res => res.json()).filter(...)

Comment: parenthesis are ok, because I am filtering the json directly (a bit unusual, I know) :)

Comment: Ideally you should not be doing it inside subscribe .. you should use flatmap or switchmap

Comment: If I use flatmap, can I still extract the `details` variable?

Comment: Yes, you need to return that in your first call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fat arrow syntax to retain `this` value.

Replace

```
function(){  // On completion

  console.log(this);

  this.http.get(...) //<- fails
```

With

```
()=>{ // On completion

  console.log(this);

  this.http.get(...)
```

Comment: This works for one layer of callback, as in the original post, but nested callbacks will run into the same problem.  In that case, you need to assign `this` to a variable, and access your object via that variable within the callback.

Comment: fat arrow syntax retains the parent functions this value, so I am not sure how nested callback affects it. As long as all the functions are fat arrow syntax, the this will be passed on.

Answer (score 1):

The second `this`, inside the subscription function, does not refer to your original object anymore.

Try adding a reference to it, before the initial http call, ex:

`let self = this;`

and use it inside your subscription callback/error function as:

`self.http.get(..)`

Comment: This answer is the sure way to avoid accidentally using the wrong object instance.